# Using rem unit in Sass percentage

Tags: css, sass

I have made a grid using sass but I would like to change the $gutter-width to 1rem but I get a syntax error from the percentage function because its expecting a pixel value.

```
$max-width: 960px;
$total-columns: 12;
$column-width: percentage(80px / $max-width);
$gutter-width: percentage(20px / $max-width);

@function column( $column-size, $gutter: $gutter-width){
  @return $column-width * $column-size - $gutter-width;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the units from a value in SASS, just divide by that unit. Eg:

```
45px / 1px = 45
```

or

```
50px / 2px = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

The percentage function expects a unitless value; you're getting the error because it's expecting a pixel value so that it can negate the pixel value from $max-width.